# Get color name from HSL

Tags: c#, colors, drawing

I'm developing an application that gets color using a color picker from the user input. values are stored as HSL model. Now my question is that is there any algorithm to find the color name base on a HSL value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942/how-to-use-hsl-in-asp-net/2504318#2504318

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using something like this?

```
yourColor = 0xFF0000;
System.Drawing.Color myColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(yourColor);
```